# Weird Bottom Margin on my Nav Bar

Tags: css, html, sass, yeoman

There’s seems to be a bottom margin attached to .nav-wrapper>ul, but aside from actually giving it a defined height (which I don't want to do) I can't figure out how to get rid of it. Can anyone help me tighten this up?

By my calc it should be resting at the bottom of the li’s…

Had to wrap the link in Google URL Shortener as it wanted me to include code...which wasn't about to happen due to it being a lot.

[My CodePen Example](http://goo.gl/OwSnWe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the spacing fix you have on your .nav-wrapper ul element:

```
.nav-wrapper ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is creating an element below your list elements and creates that empty space.
You can see this in action by changing this to:

```
.nav-wrapper ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height:0px;
}
```

But you will lose the nice even spacing you have.

Unfortunately, this method of spacing your `li` items has the side effect of the empty space beneath so your only option to get rid of this space is to change how you are spacing out the `li` elements.

I suggest the following method:

```
nav-wrapper li {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background: none;
    transition: background-color 300ms ease;
    width: 16.6666667%;
    float: left;
}

.nav-wrapper a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 128px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #34495e;
    transition: background-color 300ms ease;
}

.nav-wrapper li a:hover {
    background: #d5051d;
}
```

Comment: Darn. And there aren't too many ways I know of to evenly space li's. Thank you for your help. I'll try and figure out another way.